# How do I convert this code using promises?

Tags: node.js, callback, promise

I am new to Nodejs.I want to convert this code to promises (nodejs).This includes four callback function get(),abc1(),pqr(),xyz(). It gives error of "cannot read property 'then' of undefined" Can anyone fix it? I am trying it to convert into promises from this example [here](http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/)

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'abc',
    user: 'root',
    password: ''
});


var auth = {
    login: function (req, res) {
        var username = req.body.username || '';
        var password = req.body.password || '';
        console.log(req.body);
        //This is get() function 
        function get(err, rows) {
            connection.connect(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
                    return;
                } else {
                    console.log("connected to database");
                    connection.query("SELECT count(id) as count from abc where name=? AND email=?", [username, password], function (err, rows) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err
                        } else {

                            b = rows;
                            console.log(b);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        //this is abc1() function                
        function abc1(err, rows) {
            console.log("onresult");
            if (err) {
                throw err;
                console.log("error in Query");
            } else {
                if (rows[0].count != 1) {
                    //xyz(result,xyz);
                    res.json({
                        "status": 401,
                        "message": "Invalid credentials"
                    });
                } else {
                    connection.query("SELECT email from abc where name=? AND email=?", [username, password], function (err, rows) {});
                    //res.json(genToken("ayush"));
                }
            }
        }
        //This is xyz() function
        function xyz(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(rows);
            connection.query("SELECT name from abc where name=? AND email=?", [username, password], function (err, rows) {});
        }
        //This is pqr() Function    
        function pqr(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(rows);
        }
        get()
            .then(function (rows) {
                // do something...
                //console.log("hellow1");
                return abc1();
            })
            .then(function (rows) {
                // do something...  
                console.log("hellow2");
                return xyz();
            })
            .then(function (rows) {
                // the third and final async response
                console.log("hellow3");
                return pqr();
            })
            .then(function (rows) {
                // the third and final async response
                console.log("hellow4");
            })
            .fail(function (err) {
                // handle any error resulting from any of the above calls 
                throw err;
            })
            .done();
    }
}
```

Comment: Some language problem: "in this there are four function named as get()" - do you meant to write "is there a four parameter function name get()"? Or something else, i.e. that there are four functions name abc1(),xyz() and pqr() - oops, these are three?! Very confusing.

Comment: get(),abc1(),xyz(),pqr() -these four

Comment: You can edit your question :-) the more clear it is, the more likely people will answer.

Comment: what is `get()` and what it does? you need to return a promise in order to make `.then()` work. jquery's get (`$.get()`) for example returns a promise and you can attach to it the (for example) `.success()` function

Comment: I am new to nodejs here how to return promise

Comment: I don't see any callback functions in your code? None of those four does take a callback.

Comment: i simplify them by giving name to them (function) but now i want use promise approach ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With arguments `(err, rows)`, all four functions appear to be written as nodebacks and we can make a shrewd guess as to what the original working code looked like.

Without modification, nodebacks can only be used as nodebacks. Inserting them raw into a promise chain won't work.

But your functions will work in a promise chain after :

- Promisifying the underlying asycn functions, ie `connection`'s methods.
- Calling, in the functions, the `connection.methodAsync()` version of the methods instead of `connection.method()`.
- Returning a promise from each of your functions.

The whole thing actually works better with a little renaming/refactoring to start with a `connect()` function rather than `get()`.

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'abc',
    user: 'root',
    password: ''
});

//Promisify `connection`. 
//Lucky you, Bluebird has a `.promisifyAll()` method.
Promise.promisifyAll(connection);

//Now, `auth` will be something like this :
var auth = {
    login: function (req, res) {
        var username = req.body.username || '';
        var password = req.body.password || '';

        //Let's assume you want to build an object containing various user details
        var authObj = {
            'userName': userName,
            'email': null, //to be set later
            'name': null //to be set later
        };

        function connect() {
            return connection.connectAsync().catch(function(err) {
                throw 'Error connecting: ' + err.stack;
            });
        }

        function abc1() {
            return connection.queryAsync("SELECT count(id) as count from abc where name=? AND email=?", [username, password]).then(function (rows) {
                if (rows[0].count != 1) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
                }
            });
        }

        function xyz() {
            return connection.queryAsync("SELECT email from abc where name=? AND email=?", [username, password]).then(function(rows) {
                return rows[0].email;
            });
        }

        function pqr() {
            return connection.queryAsync("SELECT name from abc where name=? AND email=?", [username, password]).then(function(rows) {
                return rows[0].name;
            });
        }

        return connect()
        .then(abc1)//check credentials
        .then(xyz)//get email
        .then(function (email) {
            authObj.email = email;
            return pqr();//get name
        })
        .then(function (name) {
            authObj.name = name;
            return authObj;//make authObj available to auth.login()'s caller.
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // handle any error resulting from any of the above calls.
            console.log(err);
            throw err;//make the error available to auth.login()'s caller.
        });
    }
}
```

As you will see, `err` doesn't feature in the code until the bottom of `auth.login()`. It is the nature of promisified nodebacks that errors propagate down the promise chain's error path, and don't need to be handled mid-chain unless you need to do something like mid-chain error recovery.

Whereas this is good for learning how to construct a promise chain, in practice you appear already to know name and email at the outset, and you would probably choose to login and obtain other user details in one hit with suitable SQL.

Comment: Thanks Roamer..Now i am trying to convert this code using generators+promises, here is the question link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860857/avoiding-callback-hell-using-generators-and-promises-co-module

Comment: hey Roamer,it gives an error as TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: It shows an error:- Unhandled rejection Error:Invalid credentials

Comment: Looks like some debugging is required. Probably something minor.

Comment: It does not take fail function thats why it show undefined is not a fucntion error but after removing it ,the code works fine and i got the desired output thanks roamer

Comment: Sorry, it should be `.catch(...)` not `.fail(...)`. Edited.

Comment: thanks ,Can we write the same code using both generator and promises in a Co module?

Comment: I'm not an expert in generators but would imagine that yes it can be done. Realistically, I think you would only use a generator for the repeating part - ie fetching email, name etc etc. Doing the connect and login in a generator would be somewhat contrived.